# Adding more permissions to facebook LoginButton

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

Im integrating an android app with facebook application, so far I managed to do so but 
without additional permissions (upon login) can someone give me a general guidance?

Im adding the classes I used to do so - 

The main class to handle all the actions related for facebook activities -

```
public abstract class FacebookActivity extends Activity {
    // Class variables
    protected GraphUser mFacebookUser;
    protected UiLifecycleHelper mUiHelper;
    protected SessionState mSessionState;
    protected Session mSession;

    protected Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    protected FacebookDialog.Callback dialogCallback = new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall,
                Exception error, Bundle data) {
            Log.d("FacebookActivity",
                    String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall,
                Bundle data) {
            Log.d("FacebookActivity", "Success!");
        }
    };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initFacebookUser(savedInstanceState);
        mUiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        mUiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(setActivityLayout());
        InitiateUIComponents(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mUiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mUiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mUiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data,
                dialogCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mUiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mUiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    protected void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        this.mSessionState = state;
        this.mSession = session;
    }

    private void initFacebookUser(Bundle bundle) {
        if (mFacebookUser == null) {
            GetUserAsync task = new GetUserAsync();
            task.execute(new Bundle[] { bundle });
        }
    }

    protected void postStatusUpdate(String message) {
        if (mFacebookUser != null && hasPublishPermission()) {
            Request request = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(
                    Session.getActiveSession(), message, null, null,
                    new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            doOnStatusUpdate(response.getGraphObject(),
                                    response.getError());
                        }
                    });
            request.executeAsync();
        }
    }

    protected boolean hasPublishPermission() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        return session != null
                && session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
    }

    public GraphUser getFacebookUser(Bundle bundle) {
        // Method variables
        Session session;
        Request request;
        Response response;
        GraphUser sessionUser;

        session = Session.getActiveSession();

        // If the session is null try and create a new session
        if (session == null) {
            if (bundle != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, callback, bundle);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(this);
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
                        .setCallback(callback));
            }
        }

        request = new Request(session, "me", null, HttpMethod.GET);
        response = request.executeAndWait();
        if (response.getError() != null) {
            // bla bla
        } else {
            sessionUser = response.getGraphObjectAs(GraphUser.class);
            if (sessionUser != null) {
                return sessionUser;
            }
        }

        // If no user has been fetched
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to set the activity layout to use simply return the
     * layout resource id (as R.layout.layout_resouce_id)
     * 
     * @return The address to the layout resource id
     */
    protected abstract int setActivityLayout();

    /**
     * This method injects the instantiation of the UI components to the built
     * in Android onCreate activity
     */
    protected abstract void InitiateUIComponents(Bundle bundle);

    /**
     * This method handle the action to be taken after a status update (toast,
     * notify, etc.) In order to do nothing simply leave it empty Note - The
     * given parameters are simply passed on runtime
     * 
     * @param result
     *            - The post request result
     * @param error
     *            - The facebook request error
     */
    protected abstract void doOnStatusUpdate(GraphObject result,
            FacebookRequestError error);

    private class GetUserAsync extends AsyncTask<Bundle, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Bundle... bundle) {
            mFacebookUser = getFacebookUser(bundle[0]);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void input) {

        }
    }
}
```

The class I am using to register the user using facebook -

```
public class ActivityRegister extends FacebookActivity {

    // Class variables
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private EditText editTextName;
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private Intent intent;
    private UserFunctions user;
    private Button btnRegister;
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private boolean isValid;

    @Override
    protected int setActivityLayout() {
        return R.layout.activity_register_screen;
    }

    /**
     * A method to validate user given details
     * 
     * @return True in case all the details are ok false otherwise
     */
    private boolean validateUserDetails(String name, String email,
            String password) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doOnStatusUpdate(GraphObject result,
            FacebookRequestError error) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void InitiateUIComponents(Bundle bundle) {
        user = new UserFunctions();
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerBtnRegister);
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // get the data out of the fields
                editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
                editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
                editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);

                // get the text out of the edit text objects
                name = editTextName.getText().toString();
                email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
                password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                isValid = validateUserDetails(name, email, password);
                if (isValid) {
                    user.RegisterUser(name, name, email, password);
                } else {
                    gotoNextScreen();
                }
            }
        });

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
        loginButton
                .setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                        ActivityRegister.this.mFacebookUser = user;
                        if (mFacebookUser != null) {
                            gotoNextScreen();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void gotoNextScreen() {
        intent = new Intent(ActivityRegister.this, ActivityUUID.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

}
```

I did found a thread related to adding some more permissions on facebbok loginbutton widget 
they just seem to crash my app...

Please note I am using Facebook SDK version 3.6

TNX in advance

Edit:
I managed to add publish permissions by replacing the next -

loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
by 
loginButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));

Problem is now I fail to get an active user (by removing that line I do get a user after agreeing to the app conditions but by adding the GraphUser remains null..) any help??

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem too then i work with login button without publish_actions. When i need this perm, i recheck session has it or not. If not i made a request new perm from my session.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: On the contrary, this actually does appear to explain a solution to the problem.  Not every answer that starts with "I had the same problem too" is a bad one - realistically, a lot of solutions will come from people who faced **and overcame** the same issue.

Comment: sorry about reply but i bring my solution for him, maybe it not good but i only know 1 way to fix as my reply